# ngrx how to get a nested property value from the store

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

Hi I'm new to angular ngrx.

Please can you help as I do not understand how to in ngrx , to get a nested property value from mt reducer.

In the code below:
How do I get this.todoData$.data value from my reducer???????

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { increment, decrement, reset } from '../stateMan/actions/counter.actions';
import TodoItem from '../../models/TodoItem'

interface IStore {
  count: number, 
  todo: {
    data : number
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-counter',
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter.component.scss']
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {
  count$: Observable<number>;
  todoData$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<IStore>) {
    this.count$ = store.select('count');
    this.todoData$ = store.select('todo');

  }

`//////// HOW??????
  increment() {
    // How do I get this.todoData$.data????
    console.log('show todo data', this.todoData$.data)

  }

}
```

Comment: you need to subscribe to `this.todoDate$` observable like this: `this.todoData$.subscribe((todo) => console.log(todo.data))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the recommended way (and which I follow) is to use featureSelector.

I can be defined as follows -

```
export const selectTodo = createFeatureSelector<IStore, TodoState>('todo');
```

where, TodoState can be -

```
Interface TodoState = {
  data : number
}
```

After that, you can create selector to select the data -

```
const selectTododata = createSelector(
  selectTodo,
  (state: TodoState) => state.data
);
```

and then in the component, you can use that to select -

```
this.todoData$ = store.select(selectTododata);
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: is it possible to access the reducer like in react/redux?

Comment: Do you mean like mapStateToProps & connect ? I think store.select gives you similar way to access the state. I have not done that but I believe you can pass a function directly to the store.select, from which you can return portion of state if you want -

store.select(state => state.todo && state.todo.data)

for more information, please refer - https://ngrx.io/api/store/select